# iOS, App Store Connect: How to have 2 targets of application deployed to app store connec?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, app-store-connect

I would like to have 2 targets deployed to app store connect. One will be production version connected to production api. It will be processed through Test Flight then distributed via App Store. Second will be connected to development API and processed only through Test Flight for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it as 2 different apps with different bundle id's.

And only release your dev app to TestFlight.

Comment: ok so I will do this in such a way.  Copy the target add other bundle id like com.example.AppNameTest and add it to app store connect :)